# git enter password before push/pull

Tags: git

Our company is using git for source control and on my machine I can push and pull to the server without entering a password everytime, however one of my colleagues has to repeatedly enter a password which is very annoying, does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
We are not using github and we already have the ssh public keys from all the users in the authorized_keys file in the .ssh folder in the git user home directory.  I didn't do anything special for my computer, just added the ssh key like the other computers, yet I am the only one who doesn't have to repeatedly enter the password

Answer (score 3):

This is probably done by setting a password when generating your id_rsa key pair. There is some documentation on [github](http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/) about how to set this up with a password. If you wanted to up your key pair without a password then do the following commands.

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "youremail@example.com"
```

When prompted to enter a password when generating the key just leave it blank and hit enter.

Comment: he never said he was using github

Comment: GitHub has good SSH documentation even if you're hosting elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not using github, have it setup on our server

Comment: @marchinram the github documentation in question is pretty generic.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether it's asking for a password or passphrase. I'd guess it's the latter. In that case, it means the keypair that's being used for authentication was created with a passphrase. If that keypair isn't used for anything else, it's safe to just generate another and overwrite it using

```
ssh-keygen
```

followed by pressing Enter three times. If you don't want to overwrite an existing one, let me know, and I'll tell you about the options there.

Then, whether it was originally asking for a password or passphrase, you'll need to add the public half of the new keypair, located at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, to the git server you're trying to push to. If it's a gitosis or gitolite server, which it probably is, you'll have to give the public key to someone who has admin permission so they can add it to the server. If it's just a plain Linux box with a normal git repo on it (probably not), you can use

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

It will ask for your password this time, but not again thereafter.

That should cover the most likely scenarios. If it seems to not, give me more details, and I should be able to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I wanted to create an automated script to push every hour and I couldn't figure this out because I kept entering the pass phrase when I created the key.

Answer (score 2):

The other option is to keep the password on your key but use `ssh-agent` to store the password for the duration of a session.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add his public key to the authorized_keys file which is located in that git user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

1. Make sure he has an ssh-key file created
2. `scp git_user@servername:~ id_rsa.pub`
3. ssh into the server as that git user: ssh git_user@servername and enter password.
4. `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`

That will add his key to the authorized keys and he shouldn't have to enter a password.

Comment: His ssh key is already in that file, if it wasn't he wouldn't be able to logon at all.  The problem is that it always prompts him to enter the password everytime he does a pull/push and it doesn't do that for me

Comment: That's not true. You can SSH into any server that has SSH installed if you have credentials.

Comment: Ok, what I meant to say was that I already did what you mentioned and it still asks for password.

Comment: strange, I had the same problem with a colleague and we updated his key on the server and then it worked... did you compare his remote settings in .gitconfig against yours? Perhaps there is some discepancy...